# How to change MLMultiArray datatype using coremltools 4.0?

Tags: ios, swift, python-3.x, coremltools, mlmodel

I've fetching the issue while converting `.h5` to `mlmodel` using `coremltools 4.0` I want `MLMultiArray` datatype as 171 element vector of doubles instead of the Flot32 multidimensional array of floats.

Heres in my convert script for .h5 to ml model using coremltools 4.0

```
from tensorflow import keras 
import coremltools as ct


keras_model = keras.models.load_model('v1.h5')

with open("obj.names") as f:    str1 =  f.read()

class_labels = [i for i in str1.split('\n')]

class_labels.pop()


image_input = ct.ImageType(shape=(1, 416, 416, 3,),
                           bias=[-1,-1,-1], scale=1/255)

classifier_config = ct.ClassifierConfig(class_labels)

model = ct.convert(
    keras_model, inputs=[image_input] )


model.save("v1.mlmodel")
```

Run the above script with python3 and here is my model generate with output MLMultiArray with datatype Flot32 multidimensional array of floats.

[MLMultiArray with Flot32](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IimaJ.png)

Here is my working model output MLMultiArray with datatype as 171 element vector of doubles.

[MLMultiArray with Double 171](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0jcH.png)

How can I update Float to double `MLMultiArray`?

Any assistance would be appreciated